# Centos 7 Gnome 3.2 Freezes - how to diagnose?

Tags: centos, freeze, gnome

I am running gnome 3.20 on a Centos 7 machine, to run an application based on Chrominium Engine.

I am experiencing complete freezes every few hours (sometimes after 5-7 hours, sometimes after 24+ hours).

When the system freezes, the following happens:

- The machine is not responsive, mouse not moving, touchscreen not responding
- Keyboard strokes are not responding, including Ctrl+Alt+F2/3/4/5 (to change to another terminal)
- Only a boot helps (turning off and on the power switch)

The system specs are as follows:

- Board: MSI MS-98F5
- Kernel: 4.8.2
- Gnome 3.20

Peripherials and hardware:

- Dual Monitor
- One of the dual monitors has a touchscreen
- 3G Modem, connected via Ethernet
- One of the monitors is connected to the board via a VGA to LVDS convertor
- 2G RAM
- 16GB SSD HD

I've read some posts about the subject, and tried to inspect the log files:

- /var/log/messages
- XORG logs (Xorg.0.log etc)

But, I was not able to identify anything alarming (I don't know what to look for exactly, as well). Where should I start? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
Yesterday I set up 3 identical machines to run over night, and set the /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq to 1 (echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq). The machines froze and the sysrq commands didn't respond.